# How to get error output of command that is piped through "pv" command

Tags: ruby, linux

So I am trying to use PV to create a progress bar for various commands (ie. tar).  I am running these commands in a ruby script.  The problem is that since pv is the last command in the pipe chain, it is absorbing all the errors.

ie.

```
result = `tar -cpz testDir 2>&1 | pv -pterb > testTar.tar.gz`
```

The below command will not return any error if it fails (ie. run out of space in directory) because it is absorbed by the pv command. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, normally the last command counts. You need the *pipefail* option.

```
$ sh -c '                 false | true'; echo $?
0
$ sh -c 'set -o pipefail; false | true'; echo $?
1
```

There is no simple way to duplicate `pipefail` in pure Posix, but I have noticed that bash and the generally-true-to-Posix [dash(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash) does implement it.